# Work done by frictional force when rolling without slipping

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, work

When an object is rolling (no slipping) on a slope there should be a frictional force  which causes rotation. But when we use power insulation philosophy, we haven't considered about an energy loss against frictional force. So I have a doubt that when the object is rolling without slipping is there any connection between work done by force of friction and rotational kinematic energy?

Comment: Forces don't cause movement (or rotation).  They cause a change in movement (or a change in rotation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Friction in Slipping and Rolling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144524/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can friction do no work in case of pure rolling?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/465017/)